# Echoing a variable value containing closing parentheses within a parenthesized block

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let's suppose we have the following environment variable:

```bat
set "VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
```

It's ok to print its value like that:

```
echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
```

But if we will print it inside `if` body, IE:

```
if "" == "" (
    echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
)
```

We will get the following error:
`\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.`

Ok, we can workaround it by quoting what we are echo-ing:

```
if "" == "" (
    echo "VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%"
)
```

And get:
`"VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"`

But what to do if we don't want to see double quotes around the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following help you out?

```sh
@Set "VS140COMNTOOLS=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools"

@Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%

@If "" == "" (
    Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS:)=^)%
)

@If "" == "" (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=!VS140COMNTOOLS!
    EndLocal
)

@If "" == "" (
    For %%G In ("%VS140COMNTOOLS%") Do @Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%%~G
)

@Pause

@Rem Additional as per comment section

@If "" == "1" (
    Echo VS140COMNTOOLS!=%VS140COMNTOOLS:)=^)%
) Else (
    Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS:)=^)%
)

@If "" == "1" (
    Echo VS140COMNTOOLS!=%VS140COMNTOOLS:)=^)%
) Else Echo VS140COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS:)=^)%

@Pause
```

You'll note that I removed the trailing backward slash from your initial `set` value string. It is uncommon that directory paths need to have a trailing backward slash, as those are technically just path separators, and you aren't separating one in that position. If you need to use one, then use it when needed outside of the variable itself, e.g. `If Exist "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\" …`

Comment: Looks like it is required to escape '(' in the first approach too, otherwise if-else statement does not work.
Also I agree that it is bad manners to set paths environment variables with trailing backward slashes, but the variable from the topic case is set by software installer.

Comment: I don't think that is correct @NikitkoCent. I have added two further examples to hopefully show you that!

Comment: you are right, sorry. My if-else didn't work because in if body I used `echo MYVAR=%MYVAR:)=^)%` but MYVAR wasn't defined so it was expanded to `echo MYVAR=)=^)`